# Time complexity/performance of edge and vertex properties in Boost Graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, boost-property-map

Consider:

```
typedef adjacency_list<
    listS, //out edges stored as std::list
    listS, //verteices stored as std::list
    directedS,
    property<vertex_name_t, std::string>,
    property<edge_weight_t, double>
> user_graph;
```

Storage of edges and vertices as `std::list` precludes random access via `[index]`.

Consider further that property maps are defined so.

```
typedef property_map<user_graph, vertex_name_t>::type name_map_t;
typedef property_map<user_graph, edge_weight_t>::type weight_map_t;

user_graph g;
name_map_t name_map = get(vertex_name, g);
weight_map_t weight_map = get(edge_weight, g);
```

Even though random access of actual edges/vertices is not possible via `[index]`, is it guaranteed that access to the name of a vertex and weight of an edge are efficient and fast under random access like so:

```
graph_traits<user_graph>::vertex_iterator vi, vi_end;
for(tie(vi, vi_end)=vertices(g); vi != vi_end; ++vi)
    cout<<"Name of vertex is "<<name_map[*vi];//Question is, is this efficient given storage of vertices as std::list
```

Part of my confusion comes from general `std::map` characteristic that it too does not support random access (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7856473/492307))

Is it the case that whether vertices are stored as `std::vector` or `std::list` or `std::set`, regardless, access to its property maps via vertex descriptors using `some_map[vertex_descriptor]` or `some_map[*vertex_iterator]` is always guaranteed to be efficient (constant time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it guaranteed that access to the name of a vertex and weight of an edge are efficient and fast under random access like so:

Yes. The properties are actually stored *inline* with the vertex/edge *node*. A descriptor is effectively a type erased pointer to that node. `name_map[*vi]` ends up inlining to something like `get<N>(*static_cast<storage_node*>(vi))` if you imagine the property storage as a kind of tuple with a `get<>` accessor¹.

> Part of my confusion comes from general std::map characteristic that it too does not support random access

Property maps are not like std::map; They may be consecutive, they may be node-based, ordered, unordered, or even calculated. In fact Boost [Property Map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html) maybe closer to the concept of a Lense in some functional programming languages. It is a set of functions that can be used to model (mutable) projections for a given key type.

See also:

- [map set/get requests into C++ class/structure changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863061/map-set-get-requests-into-c-class-structure-changes/27863767#27863767)
- examples like [Is it possible to have several edge weight property maps for one graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979585/is-it-possible-to-have-several-edge-weight-property-maps-for-one-graph/26982767#26982767),
  and [Boost set default edge weight to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057756/boost-set-default-edge-weight-to-one/29063489#29063489)

### Curiosity Wins... Code Gen

Let's see what code gets generated:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fEn75h7dK)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <fmt/format.h>

using G =
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, // out edges stored as list
                        boost::listS, // vertices stored as list
                        boost::directedS,
                        boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string>,
                        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>>;

using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

void test(V v, E e, G const& g) {
    auto name   = get(boost::vertex_name, g);
    auto weight = get(boost::edge_weight, g);

    fmt::print("{} {}\n", name[v], weight[e]);
}

int main()
{
    G g;
    E e = add_edge(add_vertex({"foo"}, g), add_vertex({"bar"}, g), {42}, g).first;

    test(vertex(0, g), e, g);
}
```

Prints

```
foo 42
```

But more interestingly, the codegen:

```
test(void*, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, void*>, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> const&): # @test(void*, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, void*>, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> const&)
  sub rsp, 40
  mov rax, qword ptr [rsp + 64]
  movups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi + 24]
  mov rax, qword ptr [rax]
  movaps xmmword ptr [rsp], xmm0
  mov qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
  mov rcx, rsp
  mov edi, offset .L.str
  mov esi, 6
  mov edx, 173
  call fmt::v7::vprint(fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)
  add rsp, 40
  ret
```

You see, no algorithmic overhead, just dereferences.

---

¹ In reality, the properties are stored in a kind of Lisp-like list type that end up behaving similarly to a tuple. Boost Graph predates tuples by considerable time margin. I suppose if you want one can compare it closely to Boost Fusion's `map` type (which also has a type key).

Comment: Out of curiosity, checked the code-gen. https://godbolt.org/z/fEn75h7dK The proof of the pudding is in the eating, as they say

Comment: In line:  `test(vertex(0, g), e, g);`, isn't the call to `vertex(0, g)` linear time since we are storing the vertices in `std::list` ? Isn't `0` algorithmically akin to applying `[0]` on a `list` and hence linear and not constant time?

Comment: Your question is about the property map lookups, right? How you get the descriptors is your concern. In your question you used a loop (linear iteration). I chose an arbitrary valid descriptor just to call the function with. The point is that retrieving the properties from the descriptor is constant time, which was the question. (Also, one cannot apply `[0]` on a `list` so I'm not sure what that meant)